# wordpress plugin to manage the layout/design of a theme

Tags: wordpress, layout, plugins, themes

I want to use a plugin that will allow me to manage the layout/design of a wordpress site.  Is there such a plugin?

Comment: shouldn't you ask something like this in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to a framework? Or are you referring to short codes to create columns?

If you're looking for a framework I would suggest trying out

[Gantry](http://www.gantry-framework.org/) or [Pagelines](http://www.pagelines.com/) these are both pretty good... I personally like the Gantry because it supports both Joomla and Wordpress (I also, believe there is one in the works for Drupal, but I'm not 100% positive)